# application: not a procedure

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm in the process of learning Scheme. During an exercise (trying to find a specific value in a registry). When running this bit of code, I get the error message:

```
application: not a procedure;
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
given: (342 "Bike" piece 250)
arguments...: [none]
```

The code in question:

```
(define get-post
  (lambda (post varunr)
    (define find-post
      (lambda (post)
        (cond (null? post) (display "Errormessage-For-User")
              (member varunr (car (car post)))(car post)
              (else (find-post (cdr post))))))
   find-post (post))) ;; <--- Here's the error message
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define get-post
  (lambda (post varunr)
    (define find-post
      (lambda (post)
        (cond ((null? post) (display "Errormessage-For-User"))
              ((member varunr (car (car post))) (car post))
              (else (find-post (cdr post))))))
    (find-post post)))
```

Remember: in Scheme functions are called like this: `(f x)`, *not* like this: `f(x)`. And in a `cond` expression, each pair of condition/expression *must* be surrounded by `()`. You have to be careful where you put those parentheses, use your IDE's syntax highlighting and formatting capabilities to avoid errors like these.